# Symfony 4 - encrypt/decrypt fields used in doctrine with a Service?

Tags: php, symfony, encryption, symfony4

So I have fields in my database in an entity

```
class Person
{
    // other fields

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstName;

   // getters and setters
}
```

I have a Service called SecureEncryptor. That has Decrypt() and Encrypt() functions - basically you just pass the encrypted/unencrypted (respectively) string to it and it'll do the according.

Problem is I'm not sure how to use that Service in conjunction with the Entity - specifically when taking into account Forms (Types). I mean I know I could just get the field and call the Decrypt function but that wouldn't work with a Type bound to the Person Entity.

I started down the road of making a separate Entity for the decrypted Person and then I would switch it over when it was time to deal with the database but that seemed wrong.  My other idea was to call the service from the Entity but I've read that's wrong too.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

This is basically what I want to do:

```
$builder->get('dateOfBirth')
   ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
       function ($encryptedDOB) {
           return $this->encryptor->decrypt($encryptedDOB, salt); // How do I get the salt value here?
       },
      function ($decryptedDOB) {
         return $this->encryptor->encrypt($decryptedDOB, salt); // How do I get the salt value here?
      }
 ));
```

or perhaps decrypt/encrypt the data BEFORE this step but not sure how to accomplish that.

**EDIT 2:**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862168/calling-builder-getdata-from-within-a-nested-form-always-returns-null) which shows you can get to the entity data in the PRE_SET_DATA event, but you can't add a Data Transformer in there so not sure how that could work.

Comment: Are you storing the encrypted data in the database?  If so then maybe a [data transformer service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) can help with the form issue.

Comment: I like this idea, but is it possible to pass multiple fields to the Data Transformer?  For instance each row I would need to pass the field and then a salt, which is also stored in the row.

Comment: There is really no provision for passing multiple fields.  Seems like this is something best done at the database level.  Or I suppose you could store the salt along with the encrypted value.  Similar to what password_hash does.  But I would suggest you make sure you have a very good reason before you head to far down this road.  Don't really see the use case.  Decrypting the person entity after retrieving from the database might be the way to go.

Comment: Yes...that's what I'm trying to do but I can't decrypt in the Entity (I've been told that's wrong to call the Service from the Entity).  How would you suggest I go about that then?

Comment: There is a doctrine onLoad event that would probably work for decryption.  But it is going to be messy regardless.

Comment: Just seems crazy to me that something as simple as "pass two fields to a function before databinding" is so complicated.  I mean really doing this on the form level isn't really the right answer because if there was a form that didn't have the decrypt.encryption callbacks it could lead to information that wasn't encrypted properly.  It's like I need an entity wrapper or something

Comment: Did you ever get this working for Symfony? Would be interested to read that code if it's published somewhere. [I created the something similar](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-encrypt) for ZF3 using Halite for encryption and for hashing, if you're interested still.

Answer (score 9):

Well after three days of messing with this - probably 20+ hours of frustration, I finally found the CORRECT way to do this. [Entity Event Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

So I made the following changes

**app\config\services.yaml**

```
parameters:
    ...
    encryption_key: '%kernel.project_dir%/path/to/my/key'

services:
    ...
    App\EventListeners\PatientListener:
        arguments: [@session]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

And then I made the service

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListeners;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use App\Entity\Patients;
use ParagonIE\Halite\HiddenString;
use ParagonIE\Halite\KeyFactory;
use ParagonIE\Halite\Symmetric\Crypto as Symmetric;
use ParagonIE\Halite\Symmetric\EncryptionKey;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class PatientListener
{
    private $params;
    private $session;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params, 
                                 Session $session, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($entity instanceof Patients)
        {
            $this->encryptFields($entity);
        }
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($entity instanceof Patients)
        {
            $this->encryptFields($entity);
        }
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($entity instanceof Patients)
        {
            $this->decryptFields($entity);
        }
    }

    private function loadKey() : EncryptionKey
    {
        try
        {
            KeyFactory::loadEncryptionKey($this->params->get('encryption_key'));
        }
        catch(\Throwable $e)
        {
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'Unable to load encryption key!');
            $this->logger->emergency(
                'Unable to lod the encryption key!', array(
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            ));
            throw;
        }
    }

    private function encryptFields(Patients $patient)
    {
        $key = $this->loadKey();

        // Encrypt the variables
        $lastName = $this->encrypt('Last Name', $patient->getLastName(), $key);

        // Set the entity variables
        $patient->setLastName($lastName);

        return $patient;
    }

    private function encrypt($fieldName, $value, $key)
    {
        try {
            return Symmetric::encrypt(
                new HiddenString($value),
                $key
            );
        } catch(\Throwable $e)
        {
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'Unable to encrypt field');
            $this->logger->critical(
                'Unable to encrypt field "'.$fieldName.'" in Patients entity. DB update terminated.', array(
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            ));
            throw;
        }

    }

    private function decryptFields(Patients $patient)
    {
        $key = $this->loadKey();
        $id = $patient->getId();

        // Decrypt the variables
        $lastName = $this->decrypt($id, 'Last Name', $patient->getLastName(), $key);

        // Set the entity variables
        $patient->setLastName($lastName);
    }

    private function decrypt($id, $fieldName, $value, $key)
    {
        try
        {
            return Symmetric::decrypt($value, $key);
        }
        catch (\Throwable $e)
        {
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('warning', 'Unable to decrypt field');
            $this->logger->warning(
                'Unable to decrypt field "'.$fieldName.'" in Patients entity for ID: '.$id, array(
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

and now the data is encrypted when it's loaded into the database, and decrypted when it's loaded into the entity.

This way is correct because doing this any other way (custom doctrine type, data transformer, doing it in the controller etc.) there is always a chance that if someone else makes another form or uses the entity in another controller that it possibly leaves the data decrypted (aka really bad).  This way ensures the data will ALWAYS be encrypted and decrypted properly through doctrine (unless you do some custom DQL\SQL in which case you  may need to handle that yourself depending on what you are doing).

Comment: Thought you might end up with this.  Still seems to me that this sort of thing should be done at the database level.  But glad you got it working.  You should probably verify you are using the [proper change tracking policy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/change-tracking-policies.html).  By default you will always end up updating every column of every patient even if there were no changes.  Doctrine events can be tricky.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll have to look into that.  The main problem I'm having with this is that the database requires TEXT for the encrypted information, but the entity is still the correct data type for that object (since it would be converted on load into the correct format anyways).  Do you know of a way to make it skip the entity data type check if I run a make:migration?

Comment: Nope.  That is all too complicated for me.  The Doctrine ORM works great for many things but once you get outside it's little box then things get messy.

Comment: For future Googlers. Add this to only affect specific fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589587/do-something-when-one-special-field-changes-doctrine/26589755#26589755

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you looking for way to load / store encrypted data in database in transparent way. I think I would have implement [custom doctrine type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html) and decrypt / encrypt here on the load / save.

Edit: Its not that hard to implement, as base you can use `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType` which you will extend, there you are interested in `convertToPHPValue()` - Decryption and `convertToDatabaseValue()` - Encryption. For more samples look and doctrine types definition and find one which fits closest to your needs.

Comment: I can see this *might* be better, but honestly it seems to take a good knowledge of Doctrine just to implement it. Are you able to show some sample code?

Comment: I actually spent a while and figured this out but it still is not perfect as you would still need to pass the salt in the controller (unless I'm missing something).  So it's not completely transparent and that makes it harder to bind to forms as well.

Comment: For secret / salts you can put them from your service. For binding to forms - Forms is totally different layer and they get decrypted data, and set decrypted as well. It will get encrypted during doctrine flush.